# How can I get my og:image to show in facebook share situations?

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, share

One url in question is something like:

```
https://common-resources-idance-net.s3.amazonaws.com/images/model_resources/dance_genres/full/18.jpg
```

The url that comes through in facebook is:

The
    https://external-mia3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQDw1dFjILb0tqRT&w=310&h=310&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcommon-resources-idance-net.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fimages%2Fmodel_resources%2Fdance_genres%2Ffull%2F18.jpg&sx=0&sy=0&sw=310&sh=310&_nc_hash=AQA-NsHTZuEiPYBi

And it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I have a policy on the bucket that tries to whitelist referrers, which may be the problem. How can I configure this to work for facebook posts? The *facebook* etc below doesn't seem to work, and was, shall we say, "experimental". When I delete the policy, it doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Did you ask Facebook to refetch after you changed your config? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I tried this and the info is baffling: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.idance.net  it doesn't show an image, even though it finds an image url. It tells me I need og:image even though there are 6 on the page...

Comment: perhaps the issue with the original post is that there are redirects. idance.net redirects to https://www.idance.net

Comment: This also shows no image :( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=www.idance.net%2Fen%2Findex

Comment: Right now, it says _“Error while downloading … with HTTP response code: 403”_ - so your bucket still rejects requests by the Facebook scraper.